# Regular Expression for max length 12,no special character and other criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to using regular expression. I have one textbox which needs to enter code with following requirements.

I would be glad to get some help on regular expression which contains the following:

1. Total no of characters enters should be 12
2. No special character should be allowed
3. First character should be alphabet [A-Z]
4. Second character can be alphabet or number
5. If second character is alphabet rest 10 characters should be numbers
   and if second character is not alphabet rest 11 should be numbers.

I have tried following :

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9][0-9]{11}$
```

But I think this will check all the characters as numbers from 2nd characters onwards and will still allow special characters

Comment: The pattern you have is close to what you want. It's just off-by-one – `{10}` instead of `{11}` (`[A-Z]` checks the 1st character, `[A-Z0-9]` for the 2nd, leaving 3rd - 12th or 10 characters). And, by using the characters ranges of `A-Z` and `0-9` throughout, the pattern won't match any special characters.

Comment: Your requirement 5 disagrees with requirement 1, because if you allowed 11 digits after the second character that would make 13 characters.

Comment: @nnnnnn what I mean is if second character is not alphabet eg. A11111111111 (other characters should be numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can learn a bit about lookahead assertion to force some content/length stuff. Let's take this regex:

```
/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/
```

- `(?=^.{12}$)` is a positive lookahead assertion. It will ensure that the string is 12 characters long;
- `[A-Z]{1,2}` will force pattern to start with 1 or 2 letter in the range A to Z;
- `\d*` will match any number of digits
- `^..$` will anchor start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`).

And the demo:

```js
console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('123456789010'));
console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('A123456789'));
console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('A123456789011'));
console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('AAA123456789'));

console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('AA1234567890'));
console.log(/^(?=^.{12}$)[A-Z]{1,2}\d*$/.test('A12345678901'));
```

Comment: How can I modify my regular expression such that :  maxlength should be 12 (less than 12 characters can be allowed) (I have put maxlength of textbox as 12) and only numbers and alphabets are allowed and special characters are not allowed

Comment: @Scarletaarena to change the length, just replace {12} with {1,12}. It already allow only alphanumeric chars